# Как правильно подготовить запрос для mongodb в GO с использованием оператора and?

Tags: golang, mongodb, mongodb-query

Проблема - не могу правильно сделать запрос в монгу из go. 
Нужно сделать такой запрос:

```
{ 
    "manufacture" : {
        "$in" : [
            "samsung"
        ]
    }, 
    "$and" : [
        {
            "type" : {
                "$in" : [
                    "matrix", 
                    "laser"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
    paramSelect := bson.D{
        {"manufacture", bson.D{{"$in", bson.A{hp, samsung, lexmark, xerox}}}},
        {"$and",bson.M{
            "type": bson.M{
                "$in": bson.A{
                    matrix,laser},
            },
        }}}
```

но получаю панику! 
$and must be an array

Запутался окончательно с bson.M / bson.D
Подскажите как правильно запросить производителя товара с характеристиками у любого из товаров laser/matrix?

в моем случае запрос в compass работает такого вида: `{ "manufacture": { $in: ["samsung"] }, $and: [ { "type": { $in: ["matrix","laser"] } } ] }`

Answer (score 0):

Не работал с этим пакетом, но судя по документации надо что-то типа:

```golang
paramSelect := bson.D{
    {"manufacture", bson.D{
        {"$in", bson.A{hp, samsung, lexmark, xerox}}
    }},
    {"$and", bson.A{bson.M{
        "type": bson.M{
            "$in": bson.A{
                matrix,
                laser,
            },
        },
    }}},
}
```